# PHP PDO most fast way to insert 5 000 000 rows from array

Tags: php, pdo

I have simple array which has 5 000 000 indexes `$array11[$i]`. What is most best way to make 5 000 000 recs in mysql with PDO.

Comment: this is the *most fast* way to have question closed

Comment: ha ha ha.... I need help, not close question

Comment: then ask a question that complies with the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I wonder if it would be faster with reading a line from a file rather than having a large array in memory?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept in MySQL or might be in any other Database for Fast insert and Slow insert. :)

But specifically with `PDO`, you can use prepare statement so you just need to execute only. Also I would suggest to not insert all `5 000 000` in one go, do it partially.

Comment: I don't know. It's not me... Because people here is strange sometimes. I am already broke array in 4 parts. But it's not resolve speed of rec in db.

Comment: from where you are getting `5 000 000` records in your array? I mean ant source like file read, other table read, etc.

Comment: From files, i am parsed this files to get some data.

Comment: I need to carry out work on the theory of probability and mathematical statistics with real data and check results in real situations in life. For it i am do it.

Comment: So it's just first part, i have ~20 000 000 items to processing